# receiving data from api but cant setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason, I am unable to update the state of my component with the data from my fetch request. 
When I console.log, I can see that I am getting the data. I'm not sure what this could be
If this is a noob issue, please bear with me. I'm still learning.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Nav extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: "",
    posts: []
  };

  getPost = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ searchTerm: val }, () => {
      if (val !== "") {
        fetch(
          `http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=${val}&sort=relevance&limit=25`
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data.data))
          //.then(data => this.setState({ posts: data.data }))
          //.then(console.log(this.state.posts))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: How are you proving that state isn't getting updated?

Comment: `.then(data => console.log(data.data))`, doesn't return any data for the next `then()` to consume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually everything is right and going well, just your logging is wrong.

```
 .then(console.log(this.state.posts))
```

That logs the state *now* and passes the result of `console.log()` (`undefined`) to the `.then` chain as a callback which is obviously wrong. I guess you meant:

```
 .then(() => console.log(this.state.posts))
```

But that still won't work as `setState` does not trigger a state update immeadiately, but *somewhen*. After that it calls the second argument as a callback, so you should log then:

```
 .then(data => this.setState({ posts: data.data }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.posts);
 }))
```

---

Altogether:

```
    const response = fetch(
      `http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=${val}&sort=relevance&limit=25`
    ).then(res => res.json());

    // PS: I would not build up a chain if the logic is not really "chained"
    response.then(data => console.log(data.data));
    response.then(data => this.setState({ posts: data.data }, () => console.log(this.state.data)));
    response.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: ahh, I knew it was something simple. Had me frustrated for hours... Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Stizo if this answer resolved your issue, can you mark it as the selected answer?